# Shutdown Kodi with api (blackberry qml)

Tags: api, http, qml, blackberry, kodi

Hello I trying shutdown Kodi (raspberry pi) with mobile app (blackberry qml).
But I do not how.

I used this code: (in browser)

"http://[myip]:[myport]/jsonrpc?request={"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"System.Suspend","id":1}"

I used this code: (in the app)

```
function sendRequest() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var url = "http://[myip]:[myport]/jsonrpc?request={\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\": \"System.Suspend\",\"id\":1}"

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {

                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                textArea.text = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", url, true); // with "POST" I got the same problem.
    xhr.send();
}
```

I got:
{"error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error."},"id":null,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}

Remote from web browser works fine (http://[myip]:[myport])
Thank you for your answers.

********** Update: 21.10.2020 **********

I'm in progress. But I don't know what to do next.
I found some information why I have an error.
I don't know how to implement in my code.

Can you help me?
Thank you so much.

https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/pull/12281

https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=324598&highlight=json

Here's how to do it.But I can't understand it.

https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2018/09/01/kodi-remote-control-app/

This is my function (on Kodi 17.6 it is working but on Kodi 18 is not working )

```
function sendRequest() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                text.text = xhr.responseText
            }
        }
    };

    var url = 'http://<IP:PORT>/jsonrpc?request={"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "System.Shutdown"}'
    xhr.open("GET", url, true) // when I write "POST" - nothing happens
    xhr.send()
}
```

Comment: HTTP GET request should be an idempotent method and the same request should return the same response. So you probably send different request and the error code can be an indirect confirmation for that. I advice you to use some tool (I usually use Postman for that) to compare requests from 2 targets.

Comment: You have an unnecessary slash `/` before `1` in your json.

Comment: Roger Leblanc - Thank your. I repaired it. But still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should URL encode the json in your url before it's used in the open method.  Use encodeURIComponent() to do that.  Your browser is changing:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method": "System.Suspend","id":1}"
```

To:

```
%7B%22jsonrpc%22%3A%222.0%22%2C%22method%22%3A%20%22System.Suspend%22%2C%22id%22%3A1%7D%22
```

But your code is not.

Comment: Thanks, I found out I didn't have to do this.

Tested on Kodi 17.6